# Problems with ActiveReports and RichTextBox

Tags: c#, vb.net, activereports

I have a problem ActiveReports 3.0 (VB.NET) with RichTextBox. When I print an RTF text which  attribute: "\page" that it must make a BreakPage and need to print more than one page. But the report does not understand this attribute "\page" (BreakPage) and print it on a page.

Alternatively I thought to split the rtf file after the item "\page" and save to the database in more records, RTF file fragments where each row will be displayed in RichTextBox in ActiveReport. The problem is that the RTF file header will only be in first record, but other records will not have headers which will not allow them open in RTB control.

How can I split a RTF or resolve problem with ActiveReports?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the ActiveReports RichEdit control does not support page breaks.

Maybe you can make the header just a separate static RTF that you add to a group header? I'd have to see your report and what you're trying to accomplish to do more.

```
Scott Willeke
GrapeCity inc.
```

Comment: OK, I understand they can't do anything ActiveReport, but how can I split an RTF file after <BrakePage> from rtb.RTF?

Comment: You really cannot inside ActiveReports. The ActiveReports RichEdit control doesn't support page breaks.